# Qlikview - Peek() function in FOR loop not working

Tags: qlikview, peek

I have table like this:

```
     TABLE:
        LOAD * INLINE [
            SERVER
            'SERVERNAME1'
            'SERVERNAME2'
            ...
        ];
```

and loop:

```
FOR i = 1 to NoOfRows('TABLE')  

    LET v_TABLE = Peek('SERVER', $(i), 'TABLE');
    LET v_SPECIFICATION = FieldName(1, $(v_TABLE));

    trace $(v_TABLE);


    ...
    STATEMENTS
    ... 

NEXT
```

If I reload it, nothing happen, although for cycle runs thousand times, because the result of Peek() funcion is always NULL, not the value from table. Is the syntax incorrect, or is there some other mistake?

Comment: This appears to work fine for me, my trace says SERVERNAME1...SERVERNAME2 etc. I would advise calling your table something other than `TABLE` as this is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my question was wrong. In Peek() function the third parameter wasn't string, but a variable (I didnt know that this will be mistake) and after many tries, I found out two things:

- in my QV version 11.20 I have to call functions with variable parameter e.g. v_SPECIFICATION, not $(v_SPECIFICATION) (but not variable $(i), why???)
- and rows in tables are numbered from zero (sometimes, as well), so this works for me:

**LET v_TABLE = Peek('SERVER', $(i) - 1, v_SPECIFICATION);**

Its really strange for me, but learning by doing...